# How to debug a "String index out of range" error in a Java program?

Tags: java, runtime-error

```
["Exception in thread "main" 
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 2
    at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
    at Haupt.main(Haupt.java:21)"]
```

And here is my code. Why did I get this error?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Haupt {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String Wort="";
        String WortCpy="";
        String WortRev="";
        int i=0;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);


        System.out.print("Geben Sie ein Wort ein : "); //Ausgabe
        Wort = scan.nextLine(); //Eingabe
        scan.close();
        for(i=0;i < Wort.length();i++) { 
            WortCpy= WortCpy +  Wort.charAt(i); //Speichert jeden Buchstaben einzeln in Wortcpy ab
        }
        for(i=Wort.length();i>=0;i--) {
            WortRev = WortRev +  Wort.charAt(i); 
        }

        System.out.println("Wort : " + Wort);
        System.out.println("Wort Kopiert : " + WortCpy);
        System.out.println("Wort umgedreht : " + WortRev);


    }

}
```

Comment: Off-by-one error: Your second loop should start at `Wort.length() - 1` instead of `Wort.length()`.

Comment: Please start your variable names with a lowercase letter or you'll confuse 99% of java programmers (and syntax highlighters).

Comment: With code `for(i=Wort.length(); ...) {... Word.charAt(i)... }` part `Word.charAt(i)` will at first iteration behave like `Word.charAt(Word.length())`. Do you see the problem now?

Comment: I'm tempted to mark this question a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/q/18238458/3788176.

Answer (score 0):

Indexes start from `0` for a String object. So you have not index which number equals to `Wort.length()`

Try this;

```
 for(i=Wort.length()-1;i>=0;i--) {
        WortRev = WortRev +  Wort.charAt(i); 
    }
```

Comment: No joke at the same time i knowed it i changed it right now and then i saw that you writed it im so dumb wtf thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

`String.length()` returns the length of the string, but with zero based indexes, you cannot use this as a character index.
Try something like this:

```
for ( i = Wort.length()-1; i >= 0; i-- )
{
    WortRev = WortRev +  Wort.charAt(i); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where you are looping from `wort.length()` through to `0` (and vice versa) you need to use `wort.length() - 1`.

This is because the strings char array is 0 indexed (meaning that the first char is at index 0 and the last char is at length - 1). So by this logic, in your code, when the loop hits the point where `i = wort.length()` then you'll get array out of bounds error.