# Java- index out of range: 0

Tags: java

I am desperately trying to figure out a way of stopping "String index out of range: 0" errors... It happens whenever I don't enter anything and then continue execution:

```
static String getRef(Scanner Keyboard)
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);        
    String ref= "";        
    boolean valid = false;
    int errors = 0;
    boolean problem = false;

    while(valid==false)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter a reference number which is two letters followed by three digits and a letter(B for business accounts and N for non business accounts)");
        ref = keyboard.nextLine();

        for (int i=0; i<6; i++)
        {   
            if (ref.charAt(i)=='\0')            
            {
                problem = true;
            }                
        } 

        if(problem == true)
        {
            System.out.println("The reference must consist of 6 Characters");
        }
        else
        {             
            if ((Character.isDigit(ref.charAt(0))== true) || (Character.isDigit(ref.charAt(1))== true))
            {
                System.out.println("The first 2 characters must be letters");
                errors = errors + 1;
            }

            if ((Character.isDigit(ref.charAt(2))== false) || (Character.isDigit(ref.charAt(3))== false)||(Character.isDigit(ref.charAt(4))== false))
            {
                System.out.println("The 3rd,4th and 5th characters must be numbers");
                errors = errors + 1;
            }

            if ((!ref.toUpperCase().endsWith("B"))&&(!ref.toUpperCase().endsWith("N"))) 
            {
                System.out.println("The 6th character must be either B(for business accounts) or N(for non business accounts) ");
                errors = errors + 1;
            }

            if (errors==0)
            {
                valid=true;
            }
        }

    }        
    return ref;        
}
```

What I want is to be able to output an error message if the string does not contain a character at a certain index e.g. `ref.charAt(0)`.

This will help (example):

```
if(ref.charAt(aNumber)==null) { 
    // display error message 
}
```

Comment: Why did you use  6. Can't you just use string.length for same and do your logical manipulations there after.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - "String index out of range" exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319089/java-string-index-out-of-range-exception)

Comment: Why are you checking keyboard input for `'\0'`? `String`s aren't null-terminated in Java.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is here:

```
ref.charAt(i)=='\0'
```

What happens if `ref` is a zero length string? In that case, trying to access the character at index 0 (where the first character would normally be) will give you your `index out of range: 0` error. Make sure you test the string length first:

```
if (ref != null && !ref.isEmpty() &&ref.charAt(i)=='\0')  { .. }
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Adding a `length()` check

`ref` is empty (that is `""`) when you don't enter anything. So you can't get the character at `0` (or `1`, `2`, `3` ...). You can add an `if` check on the `length`, something like

```
if (ref.length() > 5) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {   
        if (ref.charAt(i) == '\0') {
            problem = true;
        }                
    } 
} else {
    System.out.println("Please enter at least 6 characters");
}
```

#### Regular Expression

It might be simpler to compile a (reusable) [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) with a *regular expression* to validate your reference criteria (2 letters, followed by 3 digits, followed b or n). Something like,

```
String ref; // <-- get input
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z]{2})(\\d{3})([B|N|b|n])");
Matcher m = p.matcher(ref);
if (m.matches()) { // <-- valid = m.matches();
    System.out.println("ref is valid");
} else {
    System.out.println("ref is not valid");         
}
```

Comment: Well, I wouldn't use `\\D{2}` to validate letters ... :P

Comment: If OP wants to accept only latin letters, then this is ok, but if he likes to accept more types of letters, then `Pattern` provides `\p{L}`, which accepts every Unicode letter.